# Multi Level Dropdown Menu - React

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

Solution: 
@the_previ answer worked, but I needed some more CSS to be how I wanted.
This would be my CSS that was added with makeStyles from materialUI (It can be an external CSS file too).

```
dropdownIcon: {
    background: "url(/images/down-chevron.png) no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "20px",
    backgroundPosition: "left",
    paddingLeft: "30px",
  },
```

This would be the result:

[image: result]

---

I know menus, are a really common problem, but I couldn't find a way to do it.
I have a component, with the lib `react-multilevel-dropdown`, that actually does exactly what I want to.

```
<Dropdown position="right" title="Todos os departamentos">
      <Dropdown.Item>Item 1</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>
        Item 2
        <Dropdown.Submenu position="right">
          <Dropdown.Item>Subitem 1</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item>Subitem 2</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Submenu>
      </Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>Item 3</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown>
```

[image: multi level menu]

This would be my component right now, and I need to add an Icon on the beginning of the title, title prop only accepts strings. (it's not mandatory to be this lib, anything functioning just like it but with an icon would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using this library is to add the icon with CSS as a background image like this:

```css
.dropdown-main {
  background: url("your-icon.svg") no-repeat;
}
```